# How to query a dynamic classname using XPath

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping, domdocument

Below is a working code that scrape a single value from an element (basically grabbing the current exchange rate value.

```
$target_url = file_get_contents('http://www.bsp.gov.ph/statistics/sdds/exchrate.htm');
$new_dom_doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors
if(!empty($target_url)){ //check if target_url is actually returned
    $new_dom_doc->loadHTML($target_url);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors from yucky target_url    
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($new_dom_doc);
    echo $xpath->query('//td[@class="xl1257110"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;        
}
```

Its working fine but the only issue is that the classname `//td[@class="xl1257110"]` is not static so the code breaks whenever the classname changes to a random value after a random period of time.

Any ideas how I can circumvent this issue?

Comment: Can you give me an example for which class it is not working?

Comment: Seems that it already changed. Can you tell me which rate exactly do you need, because I don't see elements with class `xl1257110` at this moment :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, use another marker. For example the SYMBOL text and the position of the table cell after it.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$expression = "string(//td[text() = 'IDR']/following-sibling::td[2])";

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate($expression)
);
```

Output:

```
string(8) "0.000068"
```

`//td[text() = 'IDR']` will fetch the table cell with the text content `IDR`. `following-sibling::` selects following nodes with the same parent, so `following-sibling::td` are the following `td` nodes. `[2]` is a position (they start with 1).

`string()` converts the first node in the result list into an string. You will get an empty string for an empty list. This works only with `DOMXpath::evaluate()`, not with `DOMXpath::query()`.